# No rule to make target android ndk

Tags: android, android-ndk

Установил cygwin. Android-NDK. Пытаюсь компилить tesseract либу.

> `https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two
> USER@USER-▒▒ /home/android-ndk-r6b
> $ ./ndk-build
> Install        : libjpeg.so => libs/armeabi/libjpeg.so
> make: *** No rule to make target`//home/tess-two/external/leptonlib-1.66/src/gr
> aymorphlow.c', needed by `/home/tess-two//obj/local/armeabi/objs/lept//home/tess
> -two/external/leptonlib-1.66/src/graymorphlow.o'.  Stop.`

Answer (score 2):

Tesseract компилируется на Ubuntu (последовательность на основе README). Закачать

```
wget http://tesseract-android-tools.googlecode.com/files/tesseract-android-tools-1.00.tar.gz
tar -xvzf tesseract-android-tools-1.00.tar.gz
rm -fr tesseract-android-tools-1.00.tar.gz

mkdir external
cd external

wget http://tesseract-ocr.googlecode.com/files/tesseract-3.00.tar.gz
tar -zxvf tesseract-3.00.tar.gz
rm -f tesseract-3.00.tar.gz

wget http://leptonica.googlecode.com/files/leptonlib-1.66.tar.gz
tar -zxvf leptonlib-1.66.tar.gz
rm -f leptonlib-1.66.tar.gz

git clone https://github.com/android/platform_external_jpeg/ libjpeg

export TESSERACT_PATH=${PWD}/tesseract-3.00
export LEPTONICA_PATH=${PWD}/leptonlib-1.66
export LIBJPEG_PATH=${PWD}/libjpeg
```

В файле # libjpeg/Android.mk закомментировать

```
#LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DUSE_ANDROID_ASHMEM
#LOCAL_SRC_FILES += \
#   jmem-ashmem.c
```

и раскомментировать

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += \
    jmem-android.c
```

И собрать

```
cd ..
ndk-build
```

Comment: Нету у меня убунту. А под cygwinом никак

Comment: И кстати как бы в моем файле
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
 jcapimin.c jcapistd.c jccoefct.c jccolor.c jcdctmgr.c jchuff.c \
 jcinit.c jcmainct.c jcmarker.c jcmaster.c jcomapi.c jcparam.c \
 jcphuff.c jcprepct.c jcsample.c jctrans.c jdapimin.c jdapistd.c \
 jdatadst.c jdatasrc.c jdcoefct.c jdcolor.c jddctmgr.c jdhuff.c \
 jdinput.c jdmainct.c jdmarker.c jdmaster.c jdmerge.c jdphuff.c \
 jdpostct.c jdsample.c jdtrans.c jerror.c jfdctflt.c jfdctfst.c \
 jfdctint.c jidctflt.c jidctred.c jquant1.c \
 jquant2.c jutils.c jmemmgr.c \
 jmem-android.c

Comment: Тогда заносите к ним баг на [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-android-tools/issues/list).

Comment: другие то как-то компилят.

Comment: Попробуйте сделать, чтобы make все печатал. И вообще странно. Вы пишете файл есть, (**т.е. точно под тем именем**) на которое ругань, а make ругается. Надо Makefile смотреть.

Comment: Да нормально с тем файлом все.

Answer (score 0):

Ругается, что нет исходника

```
//home/tess-two/external/leptonlib-1.66/src/graymorphlow.c
```

Там наверное есть READ.ME файл. В нем обычно пишут, например, откуда запускать Install и подобные вещи.

Можно еще Makefile (он наверное создан и не удален) посмотреть.

Comment: Да есть файл такой. И ссылку на сорцы еше я дал.

Comment: Это Винда ?  Что-то мне // в путях не нравятся.

Comment: это линукс через cygwin. Я хз что с путями и где он их коверкает.

Comment: Сама либа, глянь.
https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two

Comment: Я так понял, что надо прописать ndk-build в PATH, сделать cd в ./tess-two проекта, там установить environmen TESSERACT_PATH и проч.

Может в PATH чего не прописано или запуск не из нужного места. По сторочке $ ./ndk-build можно предположить.

Comment: export TESSERACT_PATH=${PWD}/external/tesseract-3.00
export LEPTONICA_PATH=${PWD}/external/leptonlib-1.66
export LIBJPEG_PATH=${PWD}/external/libjpeg
Делал

Comment: 1ая либа то компилится